# jsonファイルのパースについて

Tags: swift, json

パースについてお願いします。

"weather":[{"id":0,"main":"Rain","description":"light intensity shower rain","icon":"09n"}]

をパースする場合、

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: _url!,completionHandler:{data,response,error in do{

    let dict1:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
```

の後に、

```
let dict = dict1["weather"] as! NSDictionary
let id = dict2["id"] as! NSArray
```

をすると、以下のエラーが出ます。

Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM'  to 'NSDictionary'

この解決方法はどのように記述すれば回避できますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あなたの示されたJSONデータで`"weather"`に対応する値は、`[...]`の形(必ず一番外側の記号に注目してください)になっています。これはJSON object(読み込んだ後は`NSDictionary`)ではなく、JSON array(読み込んだ後は`NSArray`)になります。(`__NSArrayM`というのは`NSArray`の一種です。)

そのエラーメッセージは

> (`NSArray`の一種である)`__NSArrayM`をキャストで`NSDictionary`に変換することはできません

と言っているわけです。

JSONデータの方に目を戻しますと、`[...]`の内側の要素は`{...}`の形、つまりJSON objectが1個だけと言う状態です。あなたが扱いたいデータは、この内側のJSON objectでしょう。

つまり、「要素が1個だけ入っている配列からその要素を取り出す」と言うコードを書いてやる必要があります。

`as!`と言う演算子は「もしデータ型が間違っていたらアプリをクラッシュさせてください」と言うものですから、今回の例のようにデータ型に絶対の自信が持てない場所では使うべきではありません。

その辺を避けようとすると少々長くなりますが、例えばこんなコードになります:

```
enum MyError: Error {
    case BadJSON(String)
}

//...

do {
    guard let dict1 = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: Any] else {
        throw MyError.BadJSON("Not a dictionary")
    }
    guard let arr = dict1["weather"] as? [[String: Any]] else {
        throw MyError.BadJSON("weather is not an array of dictionaries")
    }
    //`dict["weather"]`は配列なのでその中から最初の1個を使う
    guard let dict2 = arr.first else {
        throw MyError.BadJSON("weather is empty")
    }
    //"id"の値はJSON arrayではないので、`as! NSArray`としてはダメ
    guard let id = dict2["id"] as? Int else {
        throw MyError.BadJSON("cannot get id")
    }
    print(id) //->0
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

その他にも、

- `NSArray`や`NSDictionary`ではなく、できるだけSwiftの`Array`や`Dictionary`を使った方が良い
- 読み取った結果を変更することはないのだから、`JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers`オプションは不要

と言う修正も同時に入れてしまったので、少しわかりにくい点があるかもしれませんが、何かありましたらコメント等でお知らせください。

Comment: 素早い回答がありがとうございます。(NSArrayの一種である)__NSArrayMを教えて頂く迄知りませんでした・・・勉強不足ですみません。。。おっしゃる通り、「guard let 変数 = ・・・　」で処理を無事させることに成功しました。これも勉強不足なのですが、Enumの列挙こういう具合につかっていくんですね。初見ばかりで本当に助かりました。

Comment: @T.T さん、 `__NSArrayM`については、Appleのドキュメントには一切出てきませんし、普通のSwiftの入門記事や入門書でもほとんど触れられていません。興味がおありなら「Objective-C クラスクラスタ」で調べてみると日本語の解説記事もいくらか見つかりますが、全部調べなくても「Objective-C時代のデータ型である`NSArray`や`NSDictionary`の実体は内緒のサブクラスになっていることがある」とだけ覚えておくと、エラーメッセージに見知らぬクラス名が出てきても戸惑わずに済むかと思います。データチェックをどこまできっちりやるべきかは実際には難しい問題で、私の回答でも、別のクラッシュ演算子である`!`が`data!`と言う形で使われているのにはお気づきでしょうか。JSONのパースが主題でしたので、その部分は端折ってしまったのですが、本当は`data`が`nil`でないことのチェックをきっちり入れておかないといけないところです。で、ネット上のサンプルコードには「異常なデータが来たら黙って無視してしまう」ものが多いのですが、想定外のデータが返ってきたときに原因がわからず困ることになったりします。enumで自前の`Error`型を定義するというのは他にも使えますので、ぜひいろいろなところで試してみてください。